# Custom field in SQLite SELECT query doesn't become DateTime column in DataTable after filling it

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, date, datetime

I have a field declared as datetime in the CREATE TABLE query, I call this field `BirthDay`, if I have the following query and fill in a DataTable like this:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT BirthDay FROM myTable", myConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
myDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

The column `BirthDay` of `myDataGridView` has type of `DateTime` and I can check this via  `myDataGridView.Columns["BirthDay"].ValueType`.

However if I change the SELECT query a little like this:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT CASE WHEN 1 THEN BirthDay END AS BirthDay2 FROM myTable", myConnection);
```

I expected the `BirthDay2` column is also type of `DateTime` after filling in my DataTable and bind to myDataGridView. However the type is `System.Object`?

I've tried with `CAST(... as DATETIME)` but the returned type is `System.Int64` (I understand that DATETIME in SQLite in fact corresponds to `Int64` in .NET), I wonder how I could make it return `System.DateTime` as the original column `BirthDay`.

I need the final type (can be checked via `DataGridViewColumn.ValueType`) is `DateTime` so that I can use `DataGridViewColumn.Format` to format my datetime string as what I want.

Comment: my query is just for demonstrative purpose that I want to mean my `BirthDay2` is some kind of reference to my `BirthDay` but `BirthDay` makes the final type `DateTime` while `BirthDay2` makes it `System.Object`

Answer (score 0):

Our team at work have been researching this issue for a long time. Our final conclusion is that any expression wrapping source field makes source data type unavailable. For ADO.NET providers using of expressions leads to `System.Object` final type, for ODBC provider it leads to `System.String` type. So it completely depends on data provider you use. Why does it behave in such way is a question to data provider developers (I haven't found the answer). 
By the way, .NET Framework provides a variety of tools to test whether given value is of type expected. There are only 5 basic data types in SQLite 3 (NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB). So in .NET code you can pass your value through the test for 3 most common types (INTEGER, REAL, TEXT).